# Necessary to Reproject Raster before Mosaic?

Tags: r, gis, rgdal, ogr, r-raster

I have a list of rasters which I would like to mosaic together. The projection is the same except for the utm zone. Here is the coord line from one rasterStack in UTM zone 50:

```
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=50 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Here is another rasterStack with an identical projection, save it is UTM zone 51:

```
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=51 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

When I try to mosaic without reprojecting first (as you can in other GIS), I get the following error:

```
rMosaic <- do.call(mosaic,rStacks)

    Error in compareRaster(x, extent = FALSE, rowcol = FALSE, orig = TRUE,: different CRS
```

This leads me to believe I need to reproject all of the rasterStacks. This is computationally time consuming with `projectRaster`, but I believe I can do it as follows:

```
for(i in 2:length(rStacks)){
        rStacks[[i]] <- projectRaster(from=rStacks[[i]], to=rStacks[[1]]) 
    }
```

Am I right to assume I have to re-project first? Thanks for any direction.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [gis.se], but yes, you are right in thinking the rasters must have a common CRS. For speed, you might consider using `gdalwarp`, either from the command line, or from the `gdalUtils` package. See also this [ESRI forum thread](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=995&t=245941).

Answer (score 0):

`help(mosaic)` clearly states:

> All objects must have the same origin, resolution, and coordinate
>   reference system.

Two different UTM zones are not considered to have the same reference system (the parameters are different when you look under the hood: false easting, false northing, reference meridians, etc.).

They should be reprojected to the output CRS, which should be a reference system that will be cartographically valid for a larger area, rather than continuing to use a single UTM zone, which will eventually show distortions, etc. when mapping larger areas.